# Why does one of my GenyMotion emulated devices show a black screen?

Tags: android, genymotion

I have two devices in my GenyMotion application. One is nexus 7 4.2.2 API. The other is a saumsung galaxy s4 4.3 API. The nexus emulator starts up fine and works well. However when I tried starting the s4 emulator, the android loading screen doesn't even show up, all i get is a black screen. When I go to DDMS, the devices tab tells me that the samsung galaxy s4 is online and debuggable. Does anyone know how to fix this issue? It make more sense if both show a black screen but why does one show a black screen and the other doesn't. I don't see anything out of the ordinary in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested this, and notice the blank screen is due to Genymotion version mismatch. Once i downloaded the latest genymotion (v2.3.0) , i was able to see Galaxy S4 startup properly.

If you do not see the navigation bar, you can manually enable it in `Configure virtual device`, see below.

[image]

Comment: @committedandroider In genymotion, click on your virtual device, then click on the wrench icon. It will bring up the configure.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me : In **Configure Virtual Device** (as shown in ashoke's answer) I changed Screen size to one of predefineds resolutions.