# App toolbar appears then disappears on map activity in Genymotion emulator

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-studio, genymotion

I am developing an app in Android Studio. The project's min sdk version is API 15 and the target is API 23.  The map in the maps activity is contained within a fragment and the app also has another non-googlemaps activity. Both activities have the same toolbar across the top. I am using the toolbar from the support library.  I am also running Genymotion with a Samsung Galaxy S4 API 18 Android 4.3 Emulator.  Google Play Services is installed on it and the data connection works fine.

The issue is this: If I make the non-maps activity the MAIN Launcher activity, the toolbar appears fine, if I set the MAIN Launcher activity to be the maps activity, the toolbar appears briefly for a fraction of a second and then disappears.  However, when I run the app on a real device (LG Optimus L90 with Lollipop 5.0.2), the toolbar appears and stays visible for both activities.  What could be causing this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26704269/why-does-one-of-my-genymotion-emulated-devices-show-a-black-screen?rq=1) about mismatch in genymotion.

Comment: @KENdi I followed that SO post and enabled the option in the genymotion emulator settings to "show Android navigation bar", but still the toolbar disappers. Any ideas why? Thanks.